# Ubuntu: Unable to mount NFS share

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, nfs, iscsi

I have an NFS share and an iSCSI target on my NAS. I'm trying to mount either of them on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM. I'm using Hyper-V for the hypervisor. I can connect to both the NFS and iSCSI on the Windows 10 host but cannot connect to either of them from Ubuntu. I keep getting timeouts. I've disabled the firewall and anti-virus software on the host machine with no progress.

The virtual machine is using a bridged connection and can ping internal IP's and external websites just fine. The VM can also ping the NAS but cannot SSH into it.

What steps should I try to troubleshoot this? The NAS is a QNAP T-431.

Comment: Can you telnet to the NAS over port 22?

Comment: telnet and ssh do not work.  Only ICMP

Comment: I verified that UFW is disabled, too

Comment: If you can't telnet over port 22 then you can't SSH.  When you try and fail, it should give you back a meaningful error that you can use to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: Hopefully this helps: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/troubleshooting-telnet

Comment: I get a temporary failure in name resolution, though I'm using the IP, not the hostname

Comment: I'm on my way out, but if you Google that error, that's where is go next

Comment: thanks!  fixed that error.  now I'm just getting timeouts

Comment: What happens after you connect with telnet to Port 22?  Does it show the version info?  This link might help: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2038506-is-there-a-reason-that-one-can-telnet-on-port-22-but-not-ssh

Comment: Progress...I removed my static IP and let DHCP give me an address and it works.  I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my static ip

Comment: First guess is the subnets don't match.  What is the address you are connecting to?  Connecting from?  Are they on the same VLAN?